# How to add file name to EMD function output?

Tags: r

I read a list of files as below:

```
> FilesToProcess 
[1] "ABE-084 0 min.csv"             "ABE-084 T=0 priming 2 min.csv"
[3] "ABE-084 T=100 min.csv"         "ABE-084 T=120 min read 2.csv" 
[5] "ABE-084 T=20 min 2 min.csv"    "ABE-084 T=40 min read 2.csv"  
[7] "ABE-084 T=60 min.csv"          "ABE-084 T=80 min 2 min.csv"   
[9] "ABE-084 unmilled.csv"
```

I then use an earth mover distance calculation to compare each file to the first one. The following is what I get from that:

```
lapply(seq_along(listOfFiles), function(i) emd(listOfFiles[[1]], listOfFiles[[i]]))
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 1.664257

[[3]]
[1] 1.786406

[[4]]
[1] 1.805162

[[5]]
[1] 0.9692656

[[6]]
[1] 1.483761...
```

What I would like to have as output is:

```
ABE-084 0 min             0
ABE084 T=0 priming 2 min  1.664257
ABE-084 T=100 min.csv     1.786406
etc.
```

Preferably this would be in 2 columns so I could write it to a CSV or XLS file. If I make the output a data frame I get this:

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(seq_along(listOfFiles), function(i) emd(listOfFiles[[1]], listOfFiles[[i]])))
df
  X0 X1.66425693035126 X1.78640556335449 X1.80516159534454 X0.969265580177307 X1.4837611913681
1  0          1.664257          1.786406          1.805162          0.9692656         1.483761
  X1.73942732810974 X1.51796090602875 X2.12318253517151
1          1.739427          1.517961          2.123183
```

I guess I have 2 questions.

1. How do I associate the filenames in FilesToProcess with the EMD function output?
2. How do I get this output into a 2 column data frame to export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (updated):

```
library(tibble)
enframe(`names<-`(
  vapply(seq_along(listOfFiles), function(i) emd(listOfFiles[[1]], listOfFiles[[i]]), double(1L)), 
  FilesToProcess
))
```

Comment: There are 93 values in my data sets. This code put the 93 values separated by commas then the EMD value on each line. I was hoping for the filename not the file contents.

Comment: @TryAgain12 oh so the `listOfFiles` contains datasets, not just the names of your files?

Comment: @TryAgain12 If my understanding is correct, then the updated code above should do the trick.